# is session.dataTask asynchronous in swift?

Tags: ios, swift, multithreading, nsurlsessiondatatask

I am making requests to my server using the following code:

```
let configuration = URLSessionConfiguration.default
let session = URLSession(configuration: configuration)
let dataTask = session.dataTask(with: request as URLRequest) { (data, response, error) in
     if error != nil {
          DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
              completion(nil, error as NSError?)
          })
          return
     }
     DispatchQueue.main.async(execute: {
          code...
     })    
}
dataTask.resume()
```

From what I have read this should not block the main thread but it seems to be doing just that.  Do I need to call this code after dispatching to another thread?  i.e.:

```
DispatchQueue.global(qos: DispatchQoS.QoSClass.userInitiated).async {

}
```

Or is dataTask itself requested asynchronously so as not to block the main thread and dispatching this to another thread will be redundant?

Comment: What session are you using? It's is async yes

Comment: Something else is definitely blocking it

Comment: I just edited to include the session with is default configuration

Answer (score 6):

Yes system given `URLSession` `dataTask` is `async` in nature. Whenever there is a system API call with a completion handler, the API is always `async` in nature. Concluding, the above implementation is correct. You don't need to put the task in the global queue.